# Stop script and return to beginning

Tags: python, exception

I have a python script that is using

while:

try:

except:

I am wondering how to stop it running (not exit script) and then return to the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap it with another loop, and add some conditions to avoid infinite loop.

```py
is_done = False
while is_done:
  while your_condition:
    try:
      # Your task
      is_done = True
      break
    except Exception as e:
      print(e)
      break
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have this now. when using except, just call the main function again.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).